# Ignore URLs in robot.txt with specific parameters?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I would like Google to ignore URLs like this:

`http://www.mydomain.example/new-printers?dir=asc&order=price&p=3`

In other words, all the URLs that have the parameters `dir`, `order` and `price` should be ignored. How do I do so with `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Here's a solutions if you want to disallow query strings:

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

or if you want to be more precise on your query string:

```
Disallow: /*?dir=*&order=*&p=*
```

You can also add to the robots.txt which url to allow

```
Allow: /new-printer$
```

The `$` will make sure only the `/new-printer` will be allowed.

*More info:*

http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_txt.html

http://sanzon.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/advanced-usage-of-robotstxt-w-querystrings/

Comment: this will disallow new-printers I only want to disorder the querystring part

Comment: so you want to allow `/new-printer` but not `/new-printers?dir=*&order=*&p=*?`?

Comment: Are those advanced wildcards and the allow directive supported well?

Comment: According to http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html - "there is no "Allow" field"

Comment: Taking the new-printers example a bit further, what if different combinations and orders of parameters are possible on that file.  Can you specify in a single query that a specific file should be disallowed if any kind of parameters are added to it without explicitly specifying them?  

Would...

Disallow: /new-printer?* work?

Comment: @AdamJones the last command should work. It will follow the same logic as the first condition. I never tried it so I can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: @JamieEdwards it's true that "Allow" is technically speaking not part of the standard, but most of the popular search engines do support it. Allow lines should be *before* Disallow lines though.

Comment: @BookOfZeus Will the page will be crawled or not? If we add the said condition in `robots`

Comment: There is now (as of 2019) a proposed standard undergoing ratification, and it does include Allow lines - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-koster-rep - perhaps surprisingly, it appears there was no formal "standard" previous to this, and search engines were left to their own devices to operate "by convention" with a "de facto" standard that led to spotty support for Allow lines except for the big ones (eg Google and Bing).

Answer (score 39):

You can block those specific query string parameters with the following lines

```
Disallow: /*?*dir=
Disallow: /*?*order=
Disallow: /*?*p=
```

So if any URL contains `dir=`, `order=`, or `p=` *anywhere* in the query string, it will be blocked.

Comment: Does this means that the whole page will not be crawled as long as the above condition is satisfied.

Comment: Beware: this will also block parameters which partially match expression, so not only `example.com?p=test` but also `example.com?top=test`.

Comment: If you would like to ignore those parameters regardless their position in the URL (first position or next) you can try that :

`Disallow: /*?dir=*
Disallow: /*?order=*
Disallow: /*?p=*
Disallow: /*&dir=*
Disallow: /*&order=*
Disallow: /*&p=*`

Comment: Can the `?` be ignored?

Comment: If I `Disallow: /*?*order=`, will it also disallow requests that contain `reorder=`?

Comment: dont forget User-agent: * at start of file

Answer (score 0):

Register your website with Google WebMaster Tools. There you can tell Google how to deal with your parameters.

Site Configuration -> URL Parameters

You should have the pages that contain those parameters indicate that they should be excluded from indexing via the robots meta tag. e.g.

Comment: While the original question mentions Google specifically, it's important to note that the Google WebMaster Tools would only block Google. Adding the Disallow rules in the robots.txt file would address other search engines as well.

Comment: True. It should also be clarified that robots.txt does not stop Google indexing pages but stops it reading their content. The best solution is using the robots meta tag on the page itself. This is supported by all systems.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work anymore since they removed that functionality, see https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/03/url-parameters-tool-deprecated