# robots.txt deny access to specific URL parameters

Tags: robots.txt, url-parameters

I have been trying to get an answer on this question on various Google forums but no-one answers so I'll try here at SO.

I had an old site that used different URL parameters like
`domain.com/index.php?showimage=166`
`domain.com/index.php?x=googlemap&showimage=139`

How can I block access to these pages for these parameters? Of course without my `domain.com/index.php` page being blocked?

Can this be done in robots.txt

**EDIT** *I found a post here: [Ignore urls in robot.txt with specific parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Allow: *
Disallow: /index.php?showImage=*
Disallow: /index.php?x=*
```