# Robots.txt Disallow method

Tags: html, robots.txt

I have been going through different forums and was wondering if this is correct. I am trying to disable bots from crawling queries only in specific subpages (e.g. www.website.com/subpage/?query=sample). I am trying to make sure /subpage/ does not get disallowed also. Please correct me if I am wrong.

File: robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /subpage/*?
```

Comment: You can always download the appropriate [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) or [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US) to test these things from the comfort of your own browser.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Thanks for the comment :) However, I was just wondering if the line 'Disallow:...' is valid or not. Basically I simply don't want bots to crawl queries under 'subpage'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters), you are very close

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /subpage/*?*
Allow: /subpage$
```

You can test this from the comfort of your own browser by using the appropriate [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) or [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US).

Comment: Hmm.. I do not want to disallow /subpage/ itself. Because I have /subpage/ which has a box of options that when an option is chosen, it will make the url: /subpage/?option=1. And I do not want google to crawl the query options.

Comment: Just a note beside syntax, if a page in /subpage/ is linked from anywhere it will be crawled and indexed. Will appear in SERP (with a notice rather than a content summary taken from the page). As an example [yoast ceased to disallow any supages but one](https://yoast.com/wordpress-robots-txt-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can specify query string in the `Disallow`. The value you set for `Disallow` is referenced as `Directory` in the documentation (not as `URI` or `URL`).

You can however achieve your objective by using `Sitemap.xml`. You can exclude the `URL` from sitemap that you do not want indexed.

[Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) also gives a some amount of granular control over how query string parameters should be interpreted. Not sure if that serves your purpose