# robots.txt disallow path containing a URL parameter regardless of order

Tags: seo, robots.txt

### The Problem

I am trying to block a path that contains a certain URL parameter with `robots.txt`. I want to block the path regardless of where this URL parameter appears in the query string.

### What I have tried

After reading [several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters), I have tried:

```
Disallow /*?param=
```

Also:

```
Disallow /*?param=*
```

These will only block the path if `param` is the first URL parameter. But not if it appears later in the URL.

I also tried:

```
Disallow /*?*param=*
```

While this works, it also blocks any path that has a URL parameter with suffix of `param` and as such is not an acceptable solution.

### The Question

How can I block a path that contains a specific URL parameter regardless of where it appears in the query string?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to block:

```
/path/file?param=value
/path/file?a=b&param=value
```

but you do **not** want to block:

```
/path/file?otherparam=value
/path/file?a=b&otherparam=value
```

You need to use two disallow lines, like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?param=
Disallow: /*&param=
```

There is no way to do this reliably with a single line.