# Robots.txt Query String - Couldn't Disallow

Tags: query-string, robots.txt

I have url

http://www.website.com/shopping/books/?b=9

I have disallow /?b=9 from robots.txt

as

User-agent: *
Disallow: /?b=9

But when i test this from Google Webmaster Robots.txt Test Tools.

Showing allowed while it should be display disallowed...

Please tell any wrong with my robots.txt

URL - http://www.website.com/shopping/books/?b=9

User-agent: *
Disallow: /?b=9

---

Also

there /?b=9 this will be same in all cases and /shopping/books/ will be change with different category.

How to Block this types of string ?

Disallow: /?b=9

Is it correct ?

Comment: @RolandStarke Please Describe More.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters

Comment: I can't got with your given reference because there Different Query String for Robots. Please let me know if any appropriate solution.